# How to manipulate / clear cookies with Capacitor Browser plugin

Tags: cookies, ionic4, capacitor

I have a need to clear cookies for a website I opened with Capacitor Browser Plugin.
I cannot find the way to do it.

In Capacitor Browser plugin there's a "browserPageLoaded" listener which is an ideal place to put my code in, but still i can't find any way to access cookies.
How can you access cookies from there ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately it is not possible to do this, the browser plugin uses SFSafariViewController on iOS and Chrome Custom Tabs on Android which for security reasons do not share cookies, see answer here https://github.com/ionic-team/capacitor-plugins/issues/7. To solve this problem you could use cordova's inAppBrowser which also works with Capacitor https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/in-app-browser. Among the options there is "clearcache" and "clearsessioncache". The list of options and examples are available at the following link https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/reference/cordova-plugin-inappbrowser/.

Example:

Console:

```
npm install cordova-plugin-inappbrowser
npm install @ionic-native/in-app-browser
ionic cap sync
```

Code:

```
import {
  InAppBrowser,
  InAppBrowserObject,
  InAppBrowserOptions,
} from "@ionic-native/in-app-browser/ngx";

constructor(private iab: InAppBrowser) {}

createNewPageBrowserInApp(url, target) {
    if (this.iab) {
      this.currentPageInAppBrowser = this.iab.create(
        url,
        target,
        this.options(inAppBrowserType)
      );
    }
  }

options(inAppBrowserType: InAppBrowserType): InAppBrowserOptions {
    switch (inAppBrowserType) {
      case InAppBrowserType.NavigationPage: {
        console.log("InAppBrowserType.NavigationPage");
        return {
          toolbarcolor: "#FFFFFF",
          location: "yes",
          hidden: "no",
          clearcache: "yes",
          clearsessioncache: "yes",
          zoom: "yes", //Android only
          hardwareback: "yes",
          mediaPlaybackRequiresUserAction: "no",
          hidenavigationbuttons: "no",
          navigationbuttoncolor: "#428bca",
          hideurlbar: "yes",
          shouldPauseOnSuspend: "no", //Android only
          disallowoverscroll: "no", //iOS only
          usewkwebview: "yes", //iOS only
          toolbar: "yes", //iOS only
          enableViewportScale: "no", //iOS only
          allowInlineMediaPlayback: "yes", //iOS only
          presentationstyle: "pagesheet", //iOS only
          fullscreen: "no", //Windows only
          useWideViewPort: "yes",
        };
      }
```

InAppBrowserType is an enum type for internal use

Comment: From Review: Hi, while links are a great way of sharing knowledge, they won't really answer the question if they get broken in the future. Add to your answer the essential content of the link which answers the question. In case the content is too complex or too big to fit here, describe the general idea of the proposed solution. Remember to always keep a link reference to the original solution's website. See: [How do I write a good answer?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)